# Magento: adding link in head to every frontend page

Tags: php, magento, magento-1.9

I have a module that needs a canonical link injected into `<head>` on literally every page on frontend. Is there a way to do it? Currently, given my module doesn't need its own page on frontend, nor any controllers whatsoever, I have only set the helper in my config.xml. Now, I do have an xml in layout, but the problem is that I need to change canonical link attributes based on user input(in admin), so XML doesn't fit. Yes, I could indeed fopen said fronted layout xml file, then replace what I need, then write new content back to it, but I wanted to check first whether there's other way for achieving that.

Comment: Cannot quite understand your wish are you talking about templating?

Comment: What do you mean? I'm not talking about templating. I just want to inject `<link rel="something" title="this" type="that" href="foobar">` into every page `<head>`, where `foobar` is going to be pulled from database.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can hook in on the `core_block_abstract_prepare_layout_before` event and use the Head block's addLinkRel method to add the link tag.

In your config.xml you need to define an observer like so:

```
<events>
    <core_block_abstract_prepare_layout_before>
        <observers>
            <your_module>
                <class>Your_Module_Model_Observer</class>
                <method>addCanonicalLink</method>
            </your_module>
        </observers>
    </core_block_abstract_prepare_layout_before>
</events>
```

Create an observer class in the Model directory

```
<?php
class Your_Module_Model_Observer {
    public function addCanonicalLink(Varien_Event_Observer $observer) {
        $block = $observer->getData('block');
        if ($block->getNameInLayout() === 'head') {
            // this will add <link rel="canonical" href="http://your-url.com">
            $block->addLinkRel('canonical', 'http://your-url.com');

            // If you need more attributes on the link tag use addItem instead
            // This will add <link rel="canonical" href="http://your-url" attr="Your Attribute">
            // $block->addItem('link_rel',  'http://your-url', 'rel="canonical" attr="Your Attribute"')
        }
    }
}
```

Update:

Since the core head.phtml template files run `echo $this->getChildHtml()` (render all children) it is possible to insert tags by adding a `core/text` block as a child and add a text string to it (just like you already tried with xml). If `addItem` doesn't fit your needs, this is more flexible as you can insert any string this way. Replace thie `$block->addLinkRel` line with

```
$canonical = $block->getLayout()->createBlock('core/text')
    ->setText('<link rel="canonical" href="http://your-url.com">')
$block->append($canonical);
```

Comment: Say my module is Foo/Bar(company/module), do I use `<class>Foo_Bar_Model_Observer</class>`?

Comment: That's correct. With that class name the path to the observer file should be Foo/Bar/Model/Observer.php

Comment: You will only be able to add the _rel_ and _href_ attributes to the `<link>` tag this way. Just read in your previous comment that you want _title_ and _type_ attributes as well.

Comment: In my layout file, I used setText, will I be able to use it in the observer, as well?

Comment: No the `page/html_head` block doesn't have a setText method. You need a `core/text` for that. However, the addItem method will fit your needs. Just replace the addLinkRel call with: `$block->addItem('link_rel', 'http://your-url', 'rel="canonical" type="Your type" title="your title"');`

Comment: Now I get: Recoverable Error: Argument 1 passed to Foo_Bar_Model_Observer::addCanonicalLink() must be an instance of Varien_Event, instance of Varien_Event_Observer given. Note, I've pasted config part under <frontend>.

Comment: Oops, replace `Varien_Event` with `Varien_Event_Observer` in the addCanonicalLink definition

Comment: Ok, so the observer works now, but it still doesn't add link to head. I've used Mage::log() to make sure it get's true for the if loop in observer, and it does, but doesn't really add link to the frontpage.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/134168/discussion-between-per-and-milos).

Comment: See my updated answer. I previously stated that you can not use the `setText` method on the _head_ block. While this is still true, the method you probably tried in your xml can also be used in the observer by adding a `core/text` child to _head_ and call `setText` on it.